# Extraer valores de 0 de un Map de Javascript

Tags: javascript, array

no se si es porque estoy saturado o porque estoy aprendiendo (o por los dos), pero tengo un problemilla que no logro solucionar.

He creado en javascript el siguiente Array usando la funcion new Map();

```
 let yoga = new Map([
        ['a', 'b'],
        ['a', 'b'],
        ['a', 'b'],
    ]);
```

Al hacer console log a esto, me imprime el siguiente mapa en la consola:

```
Map(1) {'a' => 'b'}
[[Entries]]
  0: {"a" => "b"}
    key: "a"
    value: "b"
```

Mi problema es que no sé cómo extraer los valores por separado, es decir, si solo quiero el valor key del contenido 0 no sé cómo sacarla. Si hago `console.log(yoga[0]);` no me devuelve nada, solo me da indefinido. ¿Perdonad de verdad mi ignorancia, pero alguien me puede hecha runa mano en esto? Gracias

Comment: Pregunta principal: ¿te fijaste en la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)?

Comment: El problema es que la documentación no está traducida para la clase Map en MDN :(

Comment: Un objeto Map tiene un orden específico, pero no puede ser indexado como si fuera un Array. Para indexarlo como quieres debes convertirlo. Para ello puedes usar `[...yoga][0]`

Comment: sip, me estoy empezando a percatar de que lo que necesito es construir un array, porque lo que va a albergar ahi es un titulo y una url

Answer (score 2):

Creo que no estás entendiendo el concepto de Map, así que permíteme una analogía: una Map es un diccionario: buscas una palabra (la clave) y te da una definición (el valor). Por tanto no es para buscar por índices, sino por claves. Y si intentas guardar varios valores con la misma clave, lo que estás haciendo es *machacando* el valor previo con el nuevo.

Te pongo un ejemplo:

```js
const miMapa = new Map([
  [1, 'uno'], //la clave es un número
  [3, 'tres'],
  ['IV', 'cuatro'], // la clave es un string
  [true, 'verdadero'] //la clave es un boolean
]);

function mostrarValores(mapa) {
  for (par of mapa.entries()) {
    console.log(par.toString());
  }
}

mostrarValores(miMapa);


// cambiamos un valor
miMapa.set(3, 'three');
mostrarValores(miMapa);

//mostramos un valor
console.log('El valor de la clave 2 es', miMapa.get(2));
```

Comment: Vale, empiezo a entender que esto no es lo que necesito exactamente y he entendido el concepto mal, tendré que mirar porque lo que necesito es un array clasico. Estoy aprendiendo y me esta costando mucho este concepto

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por vuestras respuestas,

he cambiado el sistema para extraer todo en forma de array:

```
let yoga = [
    {title: 'a', url: 'b'},
    {title: 'a', url: 'b'},
]
```

Me ha quedado claro